# Foreign key querines in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, django, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I'm new to SQLAlchemy, after coming from Django ORM. I'm trying to create a simple nested set pattern & I would like to do parent lookup. Which I would do like this in Django ORM:

```
Page.objects.get(slug="currentlevel",parent__slug="secondlevel",parent__parent__slug="firstlevel")
```

This would automagically query the database for each parent item, returning the relevant page row.

In SQLAlchemy, the best I can come up with is:

```
session.query(Page).join(Page.parent, aliased=True).filter_by(slug="child")
```

So I can query the immediate parent item, but how can I continue up the chain in one query? Dynamically if possible (arbitrary amount of levels)

Please keep in mind I'm new to SQLAlchemy, and coming from the relatively sheltered Django ORM. I'm sure there's information in the SQLAchemy docs but I've read through it and can't seem to find it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your desire to do everything within a single query is nothing but premature optimization :) Issuing 2-3-5 separate simple queries each fetching a single object by its PK may actually be faster than a single monster-query with 2-3-5 levels of self-referential joins, especially if you have many rows in the table. Even if separate queries are slightly slower - we're talking about microseconds, which is negligible in the overall scheme of things. If you consider this then things are getting much simpler :)

Comment: Another suggestion: this use-case is a textbook example where Pyramid's _URL traversal_ would shine. Traversal is awesome, try it :)

Comment: I actually am using Traversal, but using it to stack join commands. I'll do some profiling, but in general I try to avoid calls to the database as much as possible. Good chance though that I'm thinking about it wrong,

Comment: on my machine fetching a single row from a table by its PK takes 0.5ms. Fetching a single row from a query with a simplest possible self-referential join (`SELECT * FROM mytable a JOIN mytable b ON a.id=b.id WHERE a.id='boo'`) takes 0.9 ms. Fetching a single row from a query with 2 self-referential joins is about 1.2ms. So it's pretty much the same. Also consider that you'll likely need fetch the parent pages anyway, if only to display their titles in the breadcrumbs or in a menu.

Comment: Good thinking with the breadcrumbs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, all information in sqlalchemy docs under [`Self-Referential Query Strategies`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/relationships.html#self-referential-query-strategies). In which case your initial query would look something like this:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import aliased
page1 = aliased(Page)
page2 = aliased(Page)
qry = (session
        .query(Page).filter(Page.slug=='currentlevel')
        .join(page1, Page.parent).filter(page1.slug=="secondlevel")
        .join(page2, page1.parent).filter(page2.slug=="firstlevel")
        )
```

Or, using `aliased` (with `from_joinpoint`) arguments, somewhat shorter:

```
qry = (session
        .query(Page).filter(Page.slug=='currentlevel')
        .join(Page.parent, aliased=True).filter(Page.slug=="secondlevel")
        .join(Page.parent, aliased=True, from_joinpoint=True).filter(Page.slug=="firstlevel")
        )
```

Comment: Thanks for that, aliased with from_joinpoint was exactly what I was missing.